# Can't enable remote desktop on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

I'd like to access my workplace computer but my remote settings screen don't show the option to allow remote desktop on it:

Found:

[image]

Expected:

[image]

Why is that? What other settings do I need to change?

Comment: Which version of Windows 7 do you have?

Comment: It's the latest RC, b7100, installed as Home Premium.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Windows 7 Home Premium does **NOT** have Remote Desktop, so you have to use an alternative application.

However, alternatives are available for both terminal services (mstsc alternatives) or new protocols such as VNC.

Comment: Thanks. (http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/GettingReadyforWindows7/thread/0cb69a49-868b-47e0-a760-1a16567413bc). Strange choice, as I now need to double the cost to just get this feature with Professional?

Comment: Wow, so there is a 3rd party software which enables incoming RD on 7?

Comment: No I'd follow MicTech's advise: use VNC, stick with Home Premium

Comment: One last question. Is this VNC compatible with RD, or do I need its own client do do the things?

Comment: seperate client

Comment: darn it! it tooks me couple of hours to understant windows 7 home premium didnt' have rdc. Thanks!

Comment: Please update that link it redirects to page not found

Answer (score 2):

[Found this on a Microsoft forum:](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/GettingReadyforWindows7/thread/0cb69a49-868b-47e0-a760-1a16567413bc)

> The only versions with the "server" of
> Remote Desktop is Professional and
> Ultimate. Home Premium does NOT have
> this.
>
> It has Remote Desktop Connection,
> meaning it can connect to other PC's,
> but it is not able to be connected to.
>
> To the poster above, he's not good to
> go, he wanted to upgrade to Home
> Premium for $50, but its crippled
> without RDP host (what he needs), so
> he has to go for Professional for
> $100. (Prices reflect current discount
> pricing)

[More from somewhere else:](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Windows-7-Editions-Features-on-Parade-103766.shtml)

> Windows 7 Home Premium - the equivalent of Windows Vista Home Premium and of Windows XP Media Center
>
> **Availability**: worldwide via mainstream
> retail and OEM channels.
>
> **Features**:
> Aero Glass GUI, Aero Background, Aero
> Peek, Aero Snap, Live Thumbnail
> previews, Multi Touch capabilities,
> Home Group, Windows Media Center, DVD
> playback and authoring, Premium Games,
> Mobility Center.
>
> **Cut Win 7 key**
> features: Domain join, Remote Desktop
> host, Advanced Backup, EFS, Offline
> Folders

Comment: Thanks, found the same link now with the correct search terms. Sad.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that RDC is much better than the other alternatives.

If you want to enable it, you can this excellent path that do it all for you
http://thegreenbutton.com/forums/t/79427.aspx

Then you must enable the port 3389 in Windows Firewall, and voilá: RDC on Windows 7 Home Premium

Answer (score -1):

If your using a corporate domain it is possible this has been disabled in a Group Policy.

Comment: I don't know, I'm an evaluator person in my company and I doubt anybody else has W7. Before this, I used Windows XP with no problem. Is there a place I could override/change this group policy? When I installed 7 and connected to the LAN, I choose "Work network" settings.